# Itereting over an API with Json,

Tags: python, json, pandas

import requests
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

url = "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/financial-statement-growth/PETS"
JC = requests.get(url).json()

content = json.dumps(JC, indent = 4, sort_keys=True)

dates = ["PETS", "APPL"]

dates_list =[]

for dates in dates:
    JC = requests.get("https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/financial-statement-growth/"+ dates).json()

dates_list.append(JC['growth'])

dataset = pd.DataFrame(dates_list)
dataset.sample(5)

### and I get this error:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      6     JC = requests.get("https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/financial-statement-growth/"+ dates).json()
      7 
----> 8 dates_list.append(JC['growth'])
      9 
     10 dataset = pd.DataFrame(dates_list)

KeyError: 'growth'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests 
import json 
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

url = "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/financial-statement-growth/PETS" 
JC = requests.get(url).json()

content = json.dumps(JC, indent = 4, sort_keys=True)

dates = ["PETS", "AAPL", "APPL"]

dates_list =[]

for dates in dates: 

    JC = requests.get("https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/financial-statement-growth/"+ dates).json()
    if JC == {}:
        print "invalid ticker ... "
    else:
        dates_list.append(JC['growth'])


dataset = pd.DataFrame(dates_list)
print dataset
```

first the ticker APPL does not exist in SEC database https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?CIK=APPL&owner=exclude&action=getcompany 
then the the api return an empty directory where the key growth does not appear inside.  You should catch error, you can check if the dictionary is empty before add the value to the dates_lists

console output

```
fmp_team:fmp $ python stackoverflow.py 
invalid ticker ... 
                                                  0                                                  1   ...                                                 9                                                  10
0  {u'Weighted Average Shares Diluted Growth': u'...  {u'Weighted Average Shares Diluted Growth': u'...  ...  {u'Weighted Average Shares Diluted Growth': u'...                                               None
1  {u'Weighted Average Shares Diluted Growth': u'...  {u'Weighted Average Shares Diluted Growth': u'...  ...  {u'Weighted Average Shares Diluted Growth': u'...  {u'Weighted Average Shares Diluted Growth': u'...

[2 rows x 11 columns]
```